# Correct way to instantiate a groovy class

Tags: java, groovy

I want to instatiate a groovy class and i have some concerns

My first choice is to use [GroovyShell](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) :

groovy-script:

```
class Foo {
    public String doStuff(String stuff) {
        return stuff + "_utils";
    }
}
new Foo(); // ??
```

main-script :

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
Script script = shell.parse(new File(path));
def clazz = script.run();
String result = clazz.doStuff("test");
print(result); // test_utils;
```

The second option is to use [GroovyClassLoader](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html) :

groovy-script

```
class Foo {
    public String doStuff(String stuff) {
        return stuff + "_utils";
    }
}
```

main-script

```
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader();
Script script = loader.parseClass(new File(path))
Object clazz = script.newInstance();
Object[] args = new Object[1];
args[0] = "test";
String result = clazz.invokeMethod("doStuff", args);
print(result) // test_utils
```

Both will run fine, i would prefer to use GroovyShell because i use it everywhere in my current code, but i don't know if `new Foo()` inside my scripts can cause any memory leaks. Is it possible?

Comment: There is no memory leaks.

Comment: so both ways are equally fine?

Comment: GroovyShell uses GroovyClassLoader. so quite equal. except in case of GroovyShell you are actually creating two classes: `Foo` (with script that creates instance of nested class) and nested `Foo.Foo` with doStaff method. So, first case takes a bit more effort in terms of memory & cpu. But Nothing about memory leak in both cases.

Comment: wait why do i create two classes with my first method? when i do this  `String result = clazz.doStuff("test"); ` i just call a method will calling doStuff  execute   `new Foo() ` too?

Comment: but beware, the class parsing in both cases takes the most of time and memory usage.

Comment: because you have class definition and you have a code outside class. when groovy parser runs it will create a Script class with `run` method that contains all the code outside declared class.

Comment: so is there a way to get or create a Foo instance from the Script class without calling new Foo() outside the class?

Comment: do not declare class, define required methods directly in script, and don't call `script.run()`. just call `script.doStuff('test')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194490/discussion-between-panos-pap-and-daggett).

Answer (score 0):

GroovyShell uses the default GroovyClassLoader. So if you don't need any extra specific features that are provided by GroovyClassLoader, you should stick to GroovyShell to keep it simple. GroovyShell and GroovyClassLoader are instances of garbage collected and I don't believe there are memory leaks for neither of them.

Answer (score 0):

After @[daggett's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett) help i managed to find the solution that fits my needs.

I will not use groovy classes at all.

A simple example

utility groovy script :

```
String doStuff() {
    return "doStuff";
}

String doStuff2(){
    return "doStuff2";
}
```

calling the utility methods from the main groovy script

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
Script utilsScript = shell.parse(new File(PATH_TO_UTIL_SCRIPT));
String result = utilsScript.doStuff();
println(result); // doStuff;
String result2 = utilsScript.doStuff2();
println(result2); // doStuff2;
```

This is not the answer to the original question but since it fits my need i am fine.